# Failed to run project after adding atmosphere: (AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.java:52)

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, atmosphere

I wonna add some websocket functionality to gwt 2.6.1 project.
I've followed all instruction. Unfortunatelly I am getting an error:

```
   [WARN] FAILED AtmosphereServlet: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration;
```

Stacktrace:

```
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] FAILED AtmosphereServlet: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration;
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.configureFramework(AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.java:52)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:84)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:80)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:522)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
   [WARN] FAILED c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload{/,file:/C:/Mars/workspace/FenixWAR/src/main/webapp/},C:\Mars\workspace\FenixWAR\src\main\webapp: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration;
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.configureFramework(AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.java:52)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:84)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:80)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:522)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
   [WARN] FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler@da24d41: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration;
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.configureFramework(AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.java:52)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:84)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:80)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:522)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
   [WARN] FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@1a7ded65: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration;
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.configureFramework(AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.java:52)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:84)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:80)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:522)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
```

It is deployed on Jetty server using gwt eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run atmosphere on a Jetty 7.

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)
```

was added in version 3 of the servlet api. Jetty 7 implements version 2.5 of the servlet api and there fore does not implement the getServeletRegistration method. Which should explain the exception.

You can try to update you GWT Eclipse plugin to version 3.0. (You'll find it at the Eclipse market place, And make sure to uninstall the old plugin before installing the new one.)

Or you can try to work with an external server like Tomcat 7 or 8. Both supports the Servlet 3.0 API.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have my project and Yours sample project run from the same eclipse/plugin/jetty. My project doesn't work, Yours work. How is this possible? How can I check the version of jetty?

Comment: Set the logLevel to TRACE. In this case the version of jetty will be displayed in the log.